# Sending files from .net application to python application

Tags: python, .net, rest, ftp, file-transfer

i have .net web app and python app. The requirement is to pass the text files in one go from .net app to python app. Python app will further process it.

What is the best way to do it?
A> using shared location or FTP Server, where .net app will dump files, and then python app picks files from the location.

B> Or using Rest Service, where .net app will invoke python service and send multiple files, which will be processed in python app.

Please guide what is the best way  to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more factors to consider. Such as:

- the size of the files
- are there any firewalls to traverse
- what will the the files after processing
- how are you going to trigger the processing after upload
- potential future features

For example, the Secure FTP (SFTP) or HTTP server implementations you may be using may have a max file size limit (e.g. 1.18 G).
Can the .net app use ftp/sftp to access the target ftp server?
Is there a requirement to keep copies of the file (e.g. remain on the ftp server) or just keep the results?
Can your ftp server trigger the python app?
Do you have any future requirements that will tip the balance?

Is there any reason not to use REST API approach? It probably has more flexibility.